# NodeJS and PHP hosting

Tags: php, node.js, hosting

I am using nodejs and php on my website but when I want to host it on a server they told me there is no server that can run both node and php.

Is there anything that could take the place of nodejs and do the same work not requiring a server for it? I am using nodejs and socket to make realtime updates for my website .

Comment: Long story short, if you're on shared hosting then no. However there are SaaS solutions that can host for you, such as Heroku.

Comment: Any cloud or VPS server can run both PHP and Node at the same time. You get root access and can install whatever you need.

Comment: Voting to close as it does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Why do you need PHP and NodeJS? Thoses langages are not complementary, they replace each other. What you can do with PHP, you can do it with NodeJS.

Comment: how did u used nodejs and php on your website @Waleed kasem ?? I have also my web project which is created on php extension and for real time feature I tried to add nodejs and socket io feature but I wasn't able to use php and nodejs together.Did you solved that issue?

Comment: For Nodejs you can use Heroku and For PHP go with Cloudways

Comment: As of now, Cpanel is offering node 14.20.1 as recommended version, there is no 16 or 18-version support. A better option is to go with a cloud server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of options are [DigitalOcean](http://digitalocean.com), [AWS (Amazon Webservices)](http://aws.amazon.com) and [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).

Personally, I'd go with [DigitalOcean](http://digitalocean.com). IMO it's the best for small projects; user friendly (good for beginners as well as advanced users), neat stability, easy scalability and best of all: insanely affordable. You can run both in one 'droplet' as you have full control over the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it at A2 Hosting
This allows Apache to act as a Proxy to the Node aplication,

[A2 How to install and configure Node.js on managed hosting accounts](https://www.a2hosting.co.uk/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts)