# nodejs hosting with PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, node.js, express, socket.io

I have gone through [NodeJS and PHP hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298627/nodejs-and-php-hosting)

I also have  a website in PHP/Mysql and Node js. Common functionalities like login, register, manage users can be managed in PHP (Saves my time) and realtime updates in Nodejs (Learning curve). I have never bought a hosting server before. Which is better option for a newbie

1. Hosting in PHP/Mysql and in Node js 
   (Only real time updates will be managed using node js)
2. Hosting only in Node Js (Devlope entire website in Node)

Which is feasible in terms of Cost, Support and maintenance.

Is there any check list that can help me while buying a hosting server  PHP+Mysql+NodeJS OR only NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

You said you read [NodeJS and PHP hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298627/nodejs-and-php-hosting)... but the answer is in the subject.

The options are [DigitalOcean](http://digitalocean.com), [AWS (Amazon Webservices)](http://aws.amazon.com) and [Heroku](http://heroku.com).

The easiest is [DigitalOcean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298627/nodejs-and-php-hosting) according to Dencker. I personnaly tried [Heroku](http://heroku.com) and it was all I needed.